# How to see results after updating .gtkrc?

Tags: themes, gtk

I need to tweak my gtk2 theme. Currently I edit the gtkrc file, then go to System>Appearance>Customise, change the widgets to something else and then back again to see the effect.

This is slow and clumsy. Is there a command or something to trigger all gtk2+ windows to udpate? Or, is there a GUI editor where the results can be previewed immediately? (like firebug for gtk2?)

Answer (score 2):

I've used an app before that is like firebug for GTK, called [Parasite](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite/) but it can't update the widgets in the sense you are suggesting.

You could try something like:

```
sudo compiz --replace &
```

if you're using compiz, that is.

Another thing you could try would be to put the commands to change the theme in a script, and assign it to a keyboard shortcut. That way you could change your .gtkrc, hit the keyboard shortcut and watch as you save a minute of your life.

I did a quick google search and found [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566413) on ubuntu forums.
The script would look something like this (assuming the theme you want to end up with is Ambiance, and the icon theme is ubuntu-mono-dark):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Change GTK theme:
gconftool-2 --type=string -s /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme Clearlooks
gconftool-2 --type=string -s /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme Ambiance

#Change Metacity theme:
gconftool-2 --type=string -s /apps/metacity/general/theme Clearlooks
gconftool-2 --type=string -s /apps/metacity/general/theme Ambiance

#Change Icons:
gconftool-2 --type=string -s /desktop/gnome/interface/icon_theme gnome
gconftool-2 --type=string -s /desktop/gnome/interface/icon_theme ubuntu-mono-dark
```

You may still need to close and re-open applications for the changes to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

Try The Widget Factory (in ubuntu repos). Install, then run with `twf`

It shows all the different widgets and you can select a theme from the menu. It's faster than the full theme change.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change something on the panels, you can do:

```
$ killall gnome-panel
```

for Ubuntu or

```
$ killall xfce4-panel
```

for XUbuntu.

I think Gnome will immediately restart the panels, but in Xfce, you'll have to restart them again:

```
$ xfce4-panel
```

I'd imagine it'd be the same with any other "widget" you're working on. Kill the process and restart it.